# Find all simultaneously orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector defined as:
$$U = (x, y, z),$$
where the values of $x, y$ and $z$ are known.

I would like to find the vectors $V$ and $W$, where:

1. $U$ is orthogonal to $V$;
2. $U$ is orthogonal to $W$;
3. $V$ is orthogonal to $W$.

I believe there are multiple solutions for this problem, hence the 'all' in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take all the $V=(a,b,c)$ s. t.
$$xa+yb+zc=0$$
(linear system with infinite solutions) and
$$W=\pm\,U\times V$$
(cross product).

EDIT: how to solve the linear system.

If $U=(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, then any $(a,b,c)$ is solution. If $U=(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$, some component is $\ne0$. If $x\ne 0$ (the procedure is similar in the other cases) we have:
$$a=-(yb+zc)/x$$
with $b,c\in\Bbb R$ arbitrary.

Comment: Of course, this assumes OP knows how to find all solutions of $xa+yb+zc=0$. Also, I'd write $W=\pm U\times V$.

Comment: If $(a,b,c)$ is solution, then $(-a,-b,-c)$ is solution.

Comment: Yes, but for each $V$, your formula gives only one $W$; there are two values of $W$ for each $V$.

Comment: True. I will edit again if @engi wants more details about how to solve the linear system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Pleaso do, I could not write V and W as a function of (x, y, z)